# Paypal Discount - How does it work?

Tags: forms, paypal, discounts

Pretty new to Paypal.  Been using the Buy Now button on an association website, works fine for single priced items.

However, now the client wants a discount function set up.  I think the logic is simple, but for the life of me, I don't understand the docs or how to get it to work properly.

Here's the setup.  A golf outing, where someone can register themselves and up to three other players (a foursome).  For each golfer, price is the same $125.00.  However, if all four register at the same time (using one form), they would receive a $50 discount (12.50 per person or 10% off).

I've been able to figure out how to pass a quantity to paypal using a hidden form field.   But I don't understand how Paypal's discounting works.  I'm able to run logic prior to handing off to paypal which will check if there are 4 golfers, and calculate the reduced price (which would be 112.50 per golfer).

When I create a Buy Now button, I've added the list price (125.00) in the item price field on Paypal's form (and I've also attempted to leave the field blank).  I've also tried adding advanced variables in PP's build a button form, such as discounts and quantity, but these won't work either.

I'd be satisfied with using hidden form fields.  I really don't want to resort to creating another button with a different price structure that would be conditionally called if the 4 golfer discount is reached.

Any ideas?  What am I doing wrong?

TIA, Mark

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the hosted buttons created through a PayPal account? You can't modify the item details with a hosted button but if you uncheck the option in "Step 2: Track inventory, profit & loss" called "Save button at PayPal" you can get the full HTML code to change as you see fit. You'll also need to click the "Remove code protection link" to remove the encryption. 
What discount variable are you trying to pass? There is "discount_rate" that takes off a specific percentage of an order.

You could also try using a drop-down menu with price option through a Buy Now button. You can have four options where the first three are for the one, two, and three players at the correct price for each and then have the fourth option be for the discounted amount for four players. 
With Buy Now buttons, by default, a buyer can't change the quantity so if you  have option two be for two players at $250.00.

Comment: Patrick, thx for your response.  I can't change the option in step 2, so it looks like the only way for me to make this work is to create a new button with the discounted price, and pass the quantity of four.  I can present the appropriate button code when the user completes the golfer registration, but before paying.  What I'm confused by is how PPs discounting works, and difference between  discount quantities and discount amount and discount amoun 2.  I don't want any discount to trigger until the quantity of 4 is reached.

Comment: If you're modifying an existing button that has already been saved to a PayPal account you wouldn't be able to uncheck the saved button option. Creating a whole new button should get around that.
Using the "discount_amount_x" variable will only work for Upload buttons - custom buttons not created through your account but where you pass all the item details to PayPal at once when the buyer is ready to pay.